# Eclipse Java Editor Formatter adds unnecessary spaces to GWT JSNI method body

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jsni

I have declared jsni method in my Java file as follow:

```
public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
    $wnd.alert(msg);
}-*/;
```

But when I click `ctrl + shift + f` to format my code using declared formatter I am getting this:

```
public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
                                            $wnd.alert(msg);
                                            }-*/;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the proper JSNI-aware editor, Eclipse will use the JavaScript formatter for JSNI, so this is where you'll tweak those things (indentation, spacing around/inside parentheses and braces, etc.)

Comment: What Do You mean by `proper JSNI-aware editor`? You mean `GWT Java Editor`?

Comment: Ok. It helped. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't help me though :( Where do I find this proper JSNI-aware editor in eclipse?

Comment: Assuming you installed the [GWT Eclipse Plugin](https://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/GettingStarted.html), when you right-click on a `.java` file → _“Open with…”_ → _“GWT Java Editor”_ (this should be the default for a project with the GWT facet). This is from memory, I haven't used Eclipse for years…

Answer (score 3):

Follwing style is not affected by Eclipse formatter:

```
public static native void alert(String msg)
/*-{
    $wnd.alert(msg);
}-*/;
```

Comment: I prefer brecket to be in the method declaration line.

Comment: That's also possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Besides what was already mentioned up here (make sure you use GWT Java Editor), there's something else.

My GWT Java Editor was not working cause in my project I did not check the flag bellow (Right click, Properties, GWT). So make sure this is also checked:
[image]

I know it might sound weird not having this enabled in a GWT project, but this is not the 'main' GWT project, which is executed. This was a library shared in several projects.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse sees that text as a block comment.

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` then click EDIT and look in the `Comments` tab and play with the various options to see if any of them make it do what you want.

If you succeed in replicating the layout you show, it will probably mess up existing block comments, so be prepared to compromise.

Comment: Then you're out of luck.  JSNI is abusing Java source by interpreting comments as code.  That requirement is what is addressed by annotations.

Comment: I have google plugin described here: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_jsni#jsni-methods but eclipse sees java script as comment unfortunatelly.

Comment: From the link: _"The Google plugin, however, understands JSNI methods and makes working with embedded JavaScript nearly as easy as editing your regular Java code. It provides syntax coloring and auto-indent functionality"_ -- sounds to me like there's a bug, or there's another option you can set to control JSNI indentation.